# Reducing yawing in a kayak with a rudder

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

**Disclaimer**

I would first like to thank in advance the people for taking the time to read this question. Please, note that this is not either homework or an open question: I just wondered about the behaviour of a physical principle and tried to solve it by hand, but got stuck.

**Setting**

I have been wondering about how a simple rudder in a kayak works. In order to clarify the scenario a bit, a kayak is a type of boat which moves thanks to a paddler rowing on both sides of it alternatively. This alternation would produce a big yaw movement (defining the Z axis as the vertical one, parallel to gravity) each stroke. Since this movement would increase the drag of the hull in the water when trying to row in a straight line, sprint kayaks have a rudder at the stern in order to minimise it. In order to make things easier, we will assume that it is a single-place kayak and the paddler is sat in the middle of it, so that the center of mass lies just in the center of the kayak and the underwater depth of the hull is distributed uniformly along it.

In a first approach, we can assume that the movement of the paddle in the water will not be perfectly parallel to the hull but rather at an angle $\theta$. This way, having our reference frame at the very center of the kayak (and paddler) (see picture), we can decompose the force applied by the paddler into two orthogonal components in $x$ and $y$ ($F_x(t)$ and $F_y(t)$) We can even assume that these forces are sinusoids, since paddling is a periodic movement and we can decompose it by doing some Fourier analysis.

[image: Graphic design is my pasion]

The rudder consists on an airfoil oriented in the direction of displacement. Let $S$ be the area of the rudder, then it produces a force given by:

$$D_r(t) = \frac{1}{2} \rho S C_D v^2(t)$$

For a movement perpendicular to the direction of displacement (necessary to overcome the yaw motion induced by the paddler), $C_D$ will take a large value ($~1.1$), so we expect this force to be relatively large.

For this problem, I will ignore the drag produced by the hull in the water when yawing, since it will not affect the final result much.

**The problem**

I want to know how much the kayak will yaw $\theta(t)$ and where the center of rotation is.

**My attempt at solving this problem**

Let $t=0$ be the very first instant in which the paddler starts applying a force. At this moment, the velocity of the rudder in the aforementioned equation will equal $0$, so we can conclude that the kayak will inevitably yaw (even if it's less that without the rudder).

In order to obtain the yaw angle, I though a good way would be calculating the torque generated by $F_y$ and $D_r$, and applying:

$\sum \tau(t) = I \alpha(t)$

For $I$ the moment of inertia and $\alpha = \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2}$ the angular acceleration. The problem with this approach is that I do not know where the center of rotation is, so I cannot directly obtain an expression for the torques and solve the differential equation. Moreover, another difficulty is that we must divide $F$ into two orthogonal components $F_r$ and $F_\theta$ with respect to the center of rotation in order to calculate the torque applied by the paddler.

In an attempt to gain some intuition on this problem, I decided to analyse the limit cases. First, imagine there was no rudder. In that case, we would have $D_r=0$, so the only torque would be produced by the paddler. The center of rotation (assuming the center of mass is in the middle of the kayak and so in the paddler) would be the center of the kayak. Obtaining the angular acceleration and the yaw angle would be trivial.

Now, for the case of an infinitely big rudder $S\to \infty$, $D_r$ would always be large enough for compensating for the force applied by the paddle. Hence, the center of rotation would be infinitely close to the rudder, and the amplitude of yaw would be at a minimum.

Due to continuity, we know that the center of rotation will lie in between the rudder and the paddler, and its position will depend on both $F$ and $D_r$. Now, here comes the tricky part: $D_r$ also depends on $v$, which depends on both $\alpha$ and the distance from the rudder to the center of rotation.

I find myself relatively close to the final solution, since I can more or less have certain intuition about the differential equation I will have to solve, but I am not able to find the center of rotation for analysing the torques and obtaining $\alpha$. (Or, maybe, there's a different path to solve this problem)

Any help on this will be highly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

*Edit:* I would like to know the reason this question got downvoted in order to correct it

Comment: One factor you might be interested in as well is hull shape and weight distribution. For example, if you take a canoe and have a much heavier person sit at the front, a lighter one at the back, the boat is incredibly hard to steer or has very low directional stability. The back, carrying less weight, has a lower flotation depth, offers less resistance to rotation and can thus swing around to the side easily. This is why you usually should have the heavier person at the back. Something similar might affect your problem, although one could maybe take the kayak to be well balanced. (??)

Comment: @kricheli Thanks for the feedback! I was assuming that it was a one-place kayak with the paddler sat in the middle of it. This way, the weight distribution/moment of inertia can be approximated easily, and we can assume that the hull depht into the water is uniform along the kayak. I have updated the original post to clarify it :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be more realistic to assume that the paddle produces a force in the y direction only and that the point of application of the force alternates from one side of the kayak to the other (not along the centerline).

Comment: @user3141592 The assumption of a one-person kayak is very clear. It's just that the same principle as in the two-person canoe applies depending on where along the axis of the kayak the paddler is positioned.

Comment: A couple of comments here. Firstly, the force generated by a paddler is much closer to a square-wave than it is to a sine-wave. Due to the non-linearities of drag and hull reaction, the problem is probably not amenable to Fourier analysis. Secondly, the rudder doesn't act as a lifting airfoil, otherwise it would provide a continuous velocity-related torque to one side at all times. Instead it provides a reaction force to any attempt to rotate the craft in the water - so while it has a small v^2 drag, it will have a large -omega (or -omega^) reaction force.

Comment: @D.Halsey I don't think so; mainly because the movement of the paddle in the water is neither a straight line nor parallel/perpendicular to the hull at any point

Comment: @Penguino Thank you for your comment. Regarding your first point, I don't really know. While in theory it should resemble a square wave, in practice, various papers suggest that the attacking movement is somehow progressive - and so the finish of the paddle, so that the shape of the force vs. time plot looks somewhat similar to a gaussian. At this point, I cannot say whether it will be better approximated by a square wave or by a combination of cosines

Comment: @Penguino Wrt your second point, I tried to account for that. When I say that $C_D$ for the rudder is ~$1.1$, I am taking the appoximation of the drag coefficient of a flat circle accross a fluid (I found the coefficient around the internet), not the one for the symmetric airfoil. I don't really know any other way to model the reaction force in this context!

Comment: WRT first point. From my experience (a few years ago now,as an amateur competitor in paddle sports) there is a fairly long section in the 'middle' of the stroke in which the force is fairly constant, but you are corect in that it drops off at start and stop of the strokes. But more of a problem is that the paddler can significantly compensate for yaw by twisting the attack angle of the paddle in the water. A ruddered racing kayak has much better yaw stability, but even in a short rudderless slalom kayak I coul deffectively sprint in a (nearly) straight line with very little lateral deviation.

Comment: WRT second point - yes, I understand now. V^2 (for sideways V) or omega^2 response is what you have

Comment: The setup to this question is very elaborate, but does not include enough critical details for the problem to be independent of real kayaks, but is not consistent enough with real kayaks to use that information either. In practice, it seems to be conceptualizing a whitewater kayak (round flat bottom, no keel, meant to spin, ie, yaw) but with a rudder, and not a sea kayak, where the keel is the primary feature making the boat not spin (and the rudder is primarily for a rotational offset against wind and currents). Paddle strokes can be parallel to the keel, and yaw is from y offset. Etc.

Comment: @tom10 Indeed, I'm not trying to model a sea kayak nor a whitewater kayak but a sprint (flatware) kayak. They are not allowed to have keels so they use the rudder as one, hence this post. And paddle strokes are not parallel to it

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know how much the kayak will yaw $~\psi(t)~$ and where the center of rotation is.

[image]

**I) the equation of motion**

$${\frac {d}{d\tau}}\beta \left( \tau \right) -{\frac {{}{\it Fy
}-m \left( {\frac {d}{d\tau}}\psi \left( \tau \right)  \right) v
 \left( \tau \right) }{mv \left( \tau \right) }}
=0$$

$${\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}\psi \left( \tau \right) -{\frac {{\it Fy}
\,L}{\theta}}
=0$$

$${\frac {d}{d\tau}}v \left( \tau \right) -{\frac {{\it Fx}{}}{m
}}
=0$$

where

- $v~$ velocity at the center of mass
- $\psi~$ the yaw angle
- $\beta~$ side slip angle (angle between the velocity and the x
  axis)
- $\theta~$ Inertia of the kayak z direction

**II)**

you can obtain analytical solution of the EOM's and get $~v(\tau)~,\beta(\tau)~,\psi(\tau)~$

**III)**

[image]

to obtain the center of rotation $~C_R~$, you need two velocities at the x-axis, at point $~L_1$ and $~L2~$

$$\vec v_1=v(\tau)\,\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(\beta(\tau) \\
   \sin(\beta(\tau) \\
 \end{bmatrix} +\dot\psi(\tau)\,
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   L1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\vec v_2=v(\tau)\,\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(\beta(\tau) \\
   \sin(\beta(\tau) \\
 \end{bmatrix} +\dot\psi(\tau)\,
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   -L2 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

the center of rotation is the intersection point between the two lines that are perpendicular to the velocities at point $~L_1~$ and $~L_2$, thus:

$$\vec r_{L1}=\begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   L_1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}+\mu\,\begin{bmatrix}
   v_{1y} \\
   -v_{1x} \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\vec r_{L2}=\begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   -L_2 \\
 \end{bmatrix}+\lambda\,\begin{bmatrix}
   v_{2y} \\
   -v_{2x} \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

with $~\vec r_{L1}=\vec r_{L2}~$ you obtain $~\mu~$ and $~\lambda$

and for  $~F_x=A\,\cos(\omega\tau)~,F_y=A\,\sin(\omega\,\tau)~$

$$\mu=\lambda=\frac{\theta\,\omega}{A\,L(\cos(\omega\,\tau)-1)}$$

**notice** that at each time you obtain other  center of rotation

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to write this! I will take a deep look at it. As a first smallish question, the effect of the rudder seems not to be reflected in the equation of motion. Is this the case?

Comment: With the rudder you control the side slip angle ?  Hence this will effected the equation of motion and the the center of rotation